# How to fix white space error in array_count_value

Tags: php

i am making php array count value function i am taking values from file get content and using it in it and want to count values but due to space its not working properly Here is my codes

```
$data = file_get_contents('testr.txt');
preg_match_all('#mob:-(\S+)-#',$data,$matches);
$nu=$matches[1];

$n=implode($nu,',');

$n="9024453561,9024453561,9024453561,9024453561,9024453561 ";
//in value of $n i am getting spce at end so array_count _value not working

$array = array($n);
$counts = array_count_values($array);
echo $counts['9024453561'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), map over your data where your call `implode` like so:

`$n=array_map('trim', implode($nu,','));`

This will remove any white space you have in your array values.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

You do not split the string into an array by `array($n)`. Instead you get a single element containing the entire string including commas. Use `trim` and `preg_split` to get an array of values.

```
$n="9024453561,9024453561,9024453561,9024453561,9024453561 ";
$array = preg_split('~\\s*,\\s*~u', trim($n));
$counts = array_count_values($array);
echo $counts['9024453561'];
```

This also splits a string like `"  123  , 456 ,  789 "`. `\s*` means zero or more whitespaces. The double slash is to escape the slash in the string literal. `trim` removes spaces from the begin and the end of the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to go through the `implode` at all, just call `array_count_values` on your `preg_match_all` result:

```
$data = file_get_contents('testr.txt');
preg_match_all('#mob:-(\S+)-#',$data,$matches);
$nu=$matches[1];

$counts = array_count_values($nu);
echo $counts['9024453561'];
```